# IBM WebSphere XMS.Net CWSMQ0082E error

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

On several occasions I have received the following error from a .Net (C#, 4.0) application out of the blue on sending a message thru a producer:

`CWSMQ0082E: Failed to send to CompCode: 2, Reason: 2009. A problem was encountered whilst sending a message. See the linked exception for more information.`

Of course, the `LinkedException` (why not use the `InnerException` IBM???) is null i.e. no more information available.

Code I'm using (pretty straightforward):

```
var m = _session.CreateBytesMessage();
m.WriteBytes(mybytearray);

m.JMSReplyTo = myreplytoqueue;
m.SetIntProperty(XMSC.JMS_IBM_MSGTYPE, MQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM);

m.SetIntProperty(XMSC.JMS_IBM_REPORT_COA, MQC.MQRO_COD);
m.SetIntProperty(XMSC.JMS_IBM_REPORT_COD, MQC.MQRO_COA);

myproducer.Send(m, DeliveryMode.Persistent, mypriority, myttl);
```

*(Offtopic: I hate the `SetIntProperty` way of setting properties. Which <expletive deleted> came up with that idea? It takes ages to look up all sorts of constants all over the place and its allowed values.)*

The exception is thrown on the .Send method. I'm using XMS.Net (IA9H / 2.0.0.7). The [only Google result](https://www.google.com/search?q=CWSMQ0082E) that [turns up](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC74458) turns out to have a different reason code (and even if it were the same, it should be fixed in my version if I understand correctly). This occurs randomly (though it seems to happen more often when it's been a while since a message has been sent/received) and I have no way to reproduce this.

I have ab-so-lute-ly **no** idea how to troubleshoot this or even where to start looking. Is this something caused by the server-side? Is it caused by XMS.net or some underlying IBM WebSphere MQ infrastructure?

Some results that I found that *seem* similar are suggesting to set `SHARECNV` to any value higher than 0 or to "true" / "yes" but [the documentation](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/integration/support/supportpacs/individual/mp7k.pdf) explicitly tells me the default is 10. Also; I have no idea if this is the cause so changing it to another value feels like a shotgun approach.

Anybody any idea on how to go about solving this? I could of course just catch the exception, tear everything (channels, sessions, whatever) down and restart but that's just plain ugly IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2009 return code means "Connection Broken."  Basically, the underlying TCP socket is gone and the client finds out about it at the time of the API call.  It is possible to tune the channels using heartbeat and keepalive so that WMQ tries harde to keep the socket alive.  However if the socket is timed out by the underlying infrastructure, nothing WMQ can do will help.  Examples we've seen are that firewalls and load balancers are often set to detect idle connections and sever them.

Modern versions of WMQ client will attempt to [reconnect transparently](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fa70190_.htm).  The application just blocks a bit longer when this occurs.

Short of using the automatic reconnect, the only solution is in fact to rebuild the connection.  Since it will get a new connection handle, all the object handles must be rebuilt as well.

Many of the tuning functions described here are available through the [client configuration file](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/cs13350_.htm), available in v7.0 and greater clients.  In particular, the [TCP stanza](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/cs13390_.htm) of that file enables keepalive. (The TCP spec says that if keepalive is provided, it must be disabled by default.)  The QMgr has [a similar ini file](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/ic19720_.htm) with configuration stanzas, including one for keepalive.  The latest WMQ client is available as [SupportPac MQC71](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC71) if you need that.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your response. After I posted this question I did, in fact, upgrade my client to 7.1.0.0 and played with the autoreconnect feature. Turns out, the MQ server version is 6.x (don't know exactly) and for autoreconnect to work the server version needs to be 7.0.1. Since I don't have control over the "other side" there's nothing I can do about this I'm afraid.

I will look into the other suggestions you offered.

Comment: Oh, by the way, rebuilding all MQ objects (connections, sessions, producers/consumers etc.) is going to be hell. I'm considering tearing down the entire (Windows NT) service using these objects (or, at least, the communication part of it) and "restarting it" as a quick-and-dirty-but-effective-and-safe option...

Comment: That does sound a bit ugly but as you say it's quick-and-dirty-but-effective-and-safe.  V6 is end-of-life as of September so hopefully you'll have a V7.x QMgr to work with soon. If this is news to your WMQ admin teams, feel free to contact me offline and I can give them the link to the EOS announcement and talk with them about migrations. The security features in v7.1 are compelling enough to skip v7.0 altogether.

Comment: The "other end" (e.g. server-side) is a government organisation; I don't think they will update to V7 anytime soon since the current setup is pretty "new". But I like to hope they do. Fingers crossed...
About the quick-and-dirty-but-effective-and-safe hack; most (actually pretty much all) MQ-related stuff is wrapped in it's own component so I can (and probably will) only tear _that_ down and spawn a new instance of it. It's the administration of events that are listening, need to be removed/re-added etc. that bothers me, but no biggy. I'll manage and survive :-)

Comment: Hmmm...gub-mint server, eh? You're right. Better plan on v6 for another decade.  Those folks *always* buy support extensions rather than upgrade. I'm all for revenue from support extensions but it is supposed to be temporary. Maybe they are waiting for v.next++.

Comment: I have been googling for a solution some time now but I haven't found anything making sense (yet). I know I can use the .ini file but I would rather use my own app.config and/or set the value in code. The sample .config files provided in /tools/dotnet/samples do not include anything near TCP/Keepalive values and online I also found nothing, not even examples.

Comment: Seem to have found it: [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/un11340_.htm?resultof=%22%6b%65%65%70%61%6c%69%76%65%22%20%22%6b%65%65%70%61%6c%22%20)

Comment: Glad you found that because I didn't know about it. Been working with WMQ since '95 and I still learn something new about it most every day.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

In cases where the main exception is sufficient enough to indicate the error, the inner exception will be null. In your case it's MQ reason code 2009 which means a connection to queue manager has been broken. The socket through which your application and queue manager were communicating was closed for some reason. The reason for socket close could be a network blip.

Along with suggestions T.Rob noted above, You could also run a XMS and Queue manager trace to understand the problem further. Please see the Troubleshooting chapter in XMS [InfoCenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp).

HTH